# When I test my keyboard on my android device, why do I get the alert that my keyboard has stopped

Tags: android, keyboard, tablet, samsung-galaxy

I am developing a keyboard for Android devices. When I went to test it on my Samsung Galaxy J3 Mission, I went to settings/language and input/keyboard/my keyboard.

Then, I went to my texting app to test it, and an alert came up saying that my keyboard had stopped. I thought that it was just a problem with that app, so I opened up Google and tried it. I got the same alert.

I restarted my phone 3 times but I still received the same alert. I tested it on my tablet and received the alert again.

I checked my Android Studio, and I have included an image of what it said [Here](https://snag.gy/s4thCa.jpg).

I do not understand what the problem is. I checked an online tutorial from [Envato Tuts+](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) to see if I had a problem with the keyboard, but I had done everything correctly.

Do I need to add code to my Android Manifest to recognize the keyboard? Are my devices to old to read the keyboard? Do I need to add more code? Can someone please help me create this keyboard? If someone needs additional details about my code, please let me know.

Comment: Check the logcat. It sounds like your keyboard is crashing.

Comment: @dharms, is there anything specific I should be looking for in the logcat?  just see a bunch of lines of code.

Comment: Filter to just error level. I would expect to see an exception with stacktrace somewhere.